# how to get the top n values and corresponding column headers to append to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have The results of a tensorflow multi-class prediction and I have been able to get the top value for each row and its' corresponding column header (which is the most likely predicted class) to append to the original data for further analysis like so:

The original results df with the predictions odds looks kind of like the following but with 260 columns. The column headers are the 1st row of ints.. the likelihood are the row 0 ,1 and so on for millions..

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  ....... 259
0   8.840584e-08    0.000115    0.000210    0.001662    0.002789    
1   0.000312    0.000549    0.002412    0.000630    0.000077
```

The code that worked to get the top value (contained in the row) is:

```
eval_datan['odds']=predsdf.max(axis=1) #gets the largest value in the row
```

And to get the corresponding column header and append it to the original DF:

```
eval_datan['pred']=predsdf.idxmax(axis=1) #gets the column header for the largest value
```

I can't figure out how to get the top "n" in this case the top 5 maybe and add them to the original DF

the result currently looks like:

```
    agegrp  gender  race    marital_status  region  ccs1    ccs2    ccs3    ccs4    ccs5    odds    pred
0   272 284 298 288 307 101 164 53  98  200 0.066987    102
1   272 285 300 290 307 204 120 147 258 151 0.196983    47
2   272 284 298 289 307 197 2   39  253 259 0.109894    259
```

So what I want is the top 5 preds and the top 5 odds...on the end of the original data.

I've looked at nlargest in pandas but so far no luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick your top N features by changing the variable `n` below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('your_sample_data.txt', delimiter='\s+')

n=3  # Top N features
frames = []

df.T.apply(lambda x: frames.append(x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(n).index.tolist()), axis=0)

print(df)
print(df.join(pd.DataFrame(frames, columns=['ccs{}'.format(n+1) for n in range(n)])))


              0         1         2         3         4
0  8.840584e-08  0.000115  0.000210  0.001662  0.002789
1  3.120000e-04  0.000549  0.002412  0.000630  0.000077

              0         1         2         3         4 ccs1 ccs2 ccs3
0  8.840584e-08  0.000115  0.000210  0.001662  0.002789    4    3    2
1  3.120000e-04  0.000549  0.002412  0.000630  0.000077    2    3    1
```

Comment: Looks good! I'll give it a go, looks like it may be slow though but at least it should get the job done, was hoping that maybe there was some better function similar to how I did the original. So I'll leave open 'till I have a chance to verify in the am! Thanks.

Comment: I agree that there would be more elegant way. But regarding the speed, it will not be that bad compared to unknown function to me. because it depends on the number of features not records or each values in this case. `.apply(axis=0)` method should iterates only 260 times in your case(Still each 260 vectors will processed as a vector). I will leave this comment for whom intentionally dodging that method based on misunderstanding.

Comment: Many thanks, to clarify I had to modify as follows to get both the column headers and the values added to the result "eval_datan"
n=5  # Top N features
frames = []
framesv = []
predsdf.T.apply(lambda x: frames.append(x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(n).index.tolist()), axis=0)
predsdf.T.apply(lambda x: framesv.append(x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(n).tolist()), axis=0)
and:
eval_datan=eval_datan.join(pd.DataFrame(frames, columns=['ccsp{}'.format(n+1) for n in range(n)]))
eval_datan=eval_datan.join(pd.DataFrame(framesv, columns=['oddsp{}'.format(n+1) for n in range(n)]))

Comment: You may want to edit your answer for clarity? as above